# Azure : How to upload image with SAS token in React-native

Tags: azure, react-native

I am working on upload camera image on azure blob storage. I am using SAS token for uploading image.But currently getting corrupted image on azure side.I have tried :

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream( '..../Containers/Data/Application/4364E917-8704-43BA-9997-E04E3E294EC7/tmp/0C31F6EA-173C-4DBE-896F-295D87D405E0.jpg','base64' )
                .then((stream) => {
                    let data = ''
                    stream.open()
                    stream.onData((chunk) => {
                        data += chunk
                    })
                    stream.onEnd(() => {
                        console.log(data)
                    })
                }).catch((err) => { console.log( err ) });
```

I am getting base64 data from above code with I am uploading to azure. My upload code :

```
axios.put( "myurl"+azureToken,formData, {
          headers: {
             'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          hideSpinner(dispatch);
          console.log(response);
        })
```

but getting corrupted image at azure side.Confused with what should be the image format while uploading .Please suggest the workaround.

Comment: You’ll need to upload binary data instead of base64 encoded string.

Comment: @GauravMantri : ok I will try with Binary data .

Comment: @GauravMantri : Do you any sample code this ?

Comment: Please check https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/322/how-to-convert-a-base64-image-into-a-image-file-and-upload-it-with-an-asynchronous-form-using-jquery on converting a base64 string to blob. HTH.